# How to write different BindingAdapters for same binding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

Let's assume i' m programming an app showing some kind of countdown.

```
// somewhere in my fragment:
fun getCountdown(): LiveData<Int> = viewModel.countdown
// 10 ... 9 ... 8 ... etc.
```

I now want to bind this LiveData to *two* different TextViews.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countdownTextView"
    android:text="@{fragment.getCountdown}" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hurryUpTextView"
    android:text="@{fragment.getCountdown}" />
```

If i only had one of those two views, my BindingAdapter(s) would look like this:

```
// for the countdown-TextView:
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
fun bindCountdownToTextView(view: TextView, state: LiveData<LoggedInSubState>) {
    view.setText("$ Seconds remaining!")
}

// OR for the hurry-up-TextView:
@BindingAdapter("android:text")
fun bindCountdownToTextView(view: TextView, state: LiveData<LoggedInSubState>) {
    if(state.value < 3){
        view.setText("Hurry up!")
    } else {
        view.setText("Chill, you have a lot of time")
    }
}
```

Now, what's the most elegant way to use both TextViews/Adapters together?

Should i just create two LiveDatas in my fragment which map countdown to the appropriate string?

Can i somehow specify which adapter i'd like to use?

Should i (try to) write one adapter which internally differenciates between the two views?

Better suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make code simple and readable, I'll advise you choose between next approaches:

1. Use one binding adapter and supply to it already prepared data - your logic particulary will be placed in View or ViewModel.
2. Use different binding adapter names and post raw data - all work will be placed in each adapter.

What is best suited for you depends on your needs, how common is format logic and , of course, personal opinion.

Comment: Even with two different adapter names, how would i choose between the adapters?
And could you please specify the "post raw data" - part?

Comment: @m.reiter create different binding adapters like `@BindingAdapter("loggedinSubstate")
fun bindCountdownToTextView(view: TextView, state: LiveData<LoggedInSubState>)` and `@BindingAdapter("loggedinSubstate")
fun bindCountdownToTextView(view: TextView, state: LiveData<LoggedInSubState>)`. `post raw data` - pass `LiveData<LoggedInSubState>` and format it inside binding function.